# How to handle very large batch data of postgresql in pyflink using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyflink

I am getting data from postgresql in pyflink table api and then convert to datastream
and process and calculate indicators using flink and calculated indicators are stored successfully in other postgresql table.
I am using flink 1.17.1 on ubuntu 22, RAM 32GB, CPU 16 with 8 core

```
env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance()\
                    .in_streaming_mode()\
                    .build()

env.add_jars("file:///home/kafka_jars/flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.17.1.jar",
    "file:///home/kafka_jars/flink-connector-jdbc-3.1.1-1.17.jar",
    "file:///home/kafka_jars/postgresql-42.6.0.jar",
)
env.set_parallelism(16)
env.set_stream_time_characteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
env.set_runtime_mode(RuntimeExecutionMode.STREAMING)
t_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(stream_execution_environment=env,
                                    environment_settings=settings)


name = "my_catalog"
default_database = "db"
username = "postgres"
password = "123456"
base_url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432"

catalog = JdbcCatalog(name, default_database, username, password, base_url)
t_env.register_catalog("my_catalog", catalog)
t_env.use_catalog("my_catalog")


# Define a watermark strategy
watermark_strategy = (
    WatermarkStrategy.for_monotonous_timestamps()
    .with_timestamp_assigner(KlineTimestampAssigner())
)
#1billion rows at a time
query = f"SELECT * FROM data WHERE symbol = 'BTCUSDT' limit 100000000"
result_table = t_env.sql_query(query)
ds = t_env.to_data_stream(result_table).assign_timestamps_and_watermarks(watermark_strategy)
```

After executing, some insertion are successful but getting below error,

```
<_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.CANCELLED
        details = "Multiplexer hanging up"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv6:%5B::1%5D:34371 {created_time:"2023-10-05T15:23:10.876943669+00:00", grpc_status:1, grpc_message:"Multiplexer hanging up"}"
>
Exception in thread read_grpc_client_inputs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/crypto/pipeline/pipeline_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 671, in <lambda>
    target=lambda: self._read_inputs(elements_iterator),
  File "/home/crypto/pipeline/pipeline_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 654, in _read_inputs
    for elements in elements_iterator:
  File "/home/crypto/pipeline/pipeline_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 541, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/home/crypto/pipeline/pipeline_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 967, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.CANCELLED
        details = "Multiplexer hanging up"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv6:%5B::1%5D:34371 {created_time:"2023-10-05T15:23:10.876943669+00:00", grpc_status:1, grpc_message:"Multiplexer hanging up"}"
```

Comment: It's difficult to see how the traceback relates to the code. That said 32GB might not be enough memory if you're materialising 1 billion objects - you could perhaps test with some smaller resultsets and see if the error is reproduced.

Comment: Thanks @snakecharmerb for replying some insertion into PG table are successful but this might be related to rpc calls made between apache beams and flink, which I have found from different sources.

Comment: @DavidAnderson can you please give us some suggestion about how flink pipeline is processed using apache beam remote calls because I am getting error mentioned above like ``` Exception in thread read_grpc_client_inputs: MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC 
```